# Splitting string in java with multiple cases

Tags: java, string, java-8

I need to extract values from a string and insert into a list. The below is the samples

```
String k1 = "Apple";
String k2 = "Apple Orange";
String k3 = "Apple (Banana, Orange, Grape)";
String k4 = "Apple Orange (Banana, Grape)";
String k5 = "Apple Orange (Banana Ice cream, Grape)"
```

At a time a word only can be present in the string, multiple words can be present in the string , multiple words with some words in the brackets also can be present in the string . In each case, need to extract the word and store in a list. Eg

The string has two parts , the comma separated list in the bracket can be (banana , orange , grape) or (banana ice cream, orange, grape cream) or whatever , provided they are always comma separated. The other strings whatever comes before the bracket string is a single word. Example 1- > Apple Orange (Banana Ice Cream, Grape) output is [Apple orange, Banana Ice Cream, Grape] . Example 2 -> Apple Orange output is [Apple Orange]

Eg

```
k1 -> [Apple] 
k2 -> [Apple Orange]
k3 -> [Apple,Banana,Orange,Grape]
k4 -> [Apple Orange,Banana,Grape]
k5 -> [Apple Orange,Banana Ice Cream, Grape]
```

Is there any way we can extract words like the above ?

Comment: replace all (other) chars to split on by "", and then split on space

Comment: `input.split("[ (,)]+")` should do the trick. Add characters, as necessary. By the way: I assume the space prefixing `Orange` in `k4` is a typo.

Comment: @JavaProgrammer: Can a word only contain letters, case-insensitive?  (For example, no hyphens or digits?  What about `strawberry-banana`?)

Comment: please don't change the target of a question in the future, but rather open a new one instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: I changed the regular expression because the question changed.

I would use a regular expression, for brevity I just assume that you use Java 9 or newer (for the `List.of()`).

```
final String delimiter = ""\\s?,\\s?|\\s+\\(|\\)";

// expected output: [Apple Orange, Banana ice cream, Grape]
System.out.println(List.of("Apple Orange (Banana ice cream, Grape)".split(delimiter)));
```

Please note that regular expressions are not good at checking for the correct handling or nesting of parentheses, so this code doesn't care if you forget the closing or opening parenthesis, in fact a parenthesis is just "worth" about as much as a comma.

Comment: Beware! `\p{Alpha}` is not different to `[a-zA-Z]` (unless `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` has been specified to `Pattern.compile(…)`). If you want to support arbitrary Unicode letters independently to any flags, you have to use `\p{IsLetter}`.

Comment: Works well with the example above , But one question , what if i have something like this in k3 .  k3 =  "Apple (Banana Ice Cream, Orange, Grape) " . In this case i am expecting Banana Ice Cream as one word . But this gives me output like Apple,Banana,Ice,Cream,Orange,Grape while i am expecting Apple,Banana Ice Cream, Orange , Grape @cyberbrain

Comment: The string  has two parts , the comma separated list in the bracket can be (banana , orange , grape) or (banana ice cream, orange, grape cream) or whatever , provided they are always comma separated. The other strings whatever comes before the bracket string is a single word. Example 1- > Apple Orange (Banana Ice Cream, Grape) output is [Apple orange, Banana Ice Cream, Grape] .  Example 2 -> Apple Orange output is [Apple Orange]. My question had a mistake in the output given. Corrected

Comment: I updated my answer to fit the "new" question.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to extract all the words in a string and assign them to a list.

First of all, you need to take words as they are: no punctuation.

Here the method:

```
public static List<String> listOfWords(String str){

    // you need words, 
    // so everything that is not a word is used as delimiter

    String result [] = str.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

   // With the following regex you include in a "word" multiple words
   // (what you asked for)
   // String result [] = str.split( "(^\\s*)[^a-zA-Z]+(\\s*$)" );

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            list.add( result[i]);

    return list;

}
```

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    String k1 = "Apple";
    String k2 = "Apple Orange";
    String k3 = "Apple (Banana, Orange, Grape)";
    String k4 = "Apple Orange (Banana, Grape)";
    String k5 = "Apple Orange (Banana Ice cream, Grape)";

    System.out.println("List k1 : " + makeCustomListFromString(k1));
    System.out.println("List k2 : " + makeCustomListFromString(k2));
    System.out.println("List k3 : " + makeCustomListFromString(k3));
    System.out.println("List k4 : " + makeCustomListFromString(k4));
    System.out.println("List k5 : " + makeCustomListFromString(k5));
}
    
private static List<String> makeCustomListFromString(String existing) {
    
    return Arrays.asList(existing.replaceAll("\\(", ",")
            .replaceAll("\\)", "")
            .replaceAll(", ", ",")
            .replaceAll(" ,", ",")
            .split(","));
}
```

1. Replace the opening bracket with a coma ["(" -> ","]
2. Remove the closing bracket [")" -> ""]
3. Remove extra spaces before and after the coma
4. Split the string with coma as a separator
5. Convert the array to a list